# Is it possible to prove that for any injective function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ if $f(x)>f^{-1}(x)$ then $f(x)>x$?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, functions

So I just came up with this question in my brain, when thinking about that the inverse function has a graph that is symmetric to the original function's graph about the line $y=x$. Then if $f(x)>f^{-1}(x)$ the curve of $f$ should be strictly above $f^{-1}$ without any intersection, and by my instinct I think it shall be able to deduce that $f(x)>x$ for all $x$, but I do not know how to prove this either algebraically or rigorously graphically. So is this statement true? And if so, how can it be proved?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you claiming that the fact that $f(x)>f^{-1}(x)$ for all $x\in \operatorname{im}f$ should imply that, for all $y$, $f(y)>y$, or are you claiming that for all $x\in \operatorname{im}f$, $f(x)\le f^{-1}(x)$ or $f(x)>x$?

Comment: True if $f$ is continuous, counterexamples exist for discontinuous functions.